# Files.lines(.., StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) getting MalformedInputException, but bufferedReader.lines() witht line.getBytes("UTF-8")-not

Tags: java

Читается одни и тот же файл во этим кодом.

```
String inputFile = options.getRemotePath();
    AtomicLong numberLine1 = new AtomicLong();
    AtomicReference<String> lastLineRead1 = new AtomicReference<>("");

    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        Stream<String> lines = bufferedReader.lines();
        lines.map(line -> "" + line)
                .forEach(line -> {
            numberLine1.getAndIncrement();
            lastLineRead1.set(line);
             
                    byte[] myBytes = line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    try {
                        myBytes = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        LOGGER.error("numberLine:" + numberLine1 + "\nlastLineRead:" + lastLineRead1,e);
                    }

                });
    }
    LOGGER.error("numberLine:" + numberLine1 + "\nlastLineRead:" + lastLineRead1);
```

я не получаю ни каких сообщений об ощибке. Т.е. все строки в UTF_8

```
Path pathFaDetailPath = Paths.get(inputFile);
    AtomicLong numberLine = new AtomicLong();
    AtomicReference<String> lastLineRead = new AtomicReference<>("");
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(pathFaDetailPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        lines.map(line -> "" + line)
                .forEach(line -> {
            numberLine.getAndIncrement();
            lastLineRead.set(line);
        });
    } catch (UncheckedIOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("numberLine:" + numberLine + "\nlastLineRead:" + lastLineRead,e);
    }
```

читая во этим кодом файл, получаю сообщние об ошибке
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.io.BufferedReader$1.hasNext(BufferedReader.java:574)

Где проблема bufferedReader.lines() или Files.lines?

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, возможно дело в специфическом входном файле или в том, что файлы разные.

Comment: файл одни и тот же. Размер 600Мб.

Comment: lastLineRead:SP/PE864AAS|12857930||134650||222|MST||0|SPECIAL||SP|SPWA|External|0|2|||5|0||||||Cedric|Slye|PECORA ANODIZED ALUMINUM SAUSAGES 12/CASE #804||||1|1|||6.85||EA|0

Comment: lastLineRead:SP/MAXREPAIR(TONYGENIER)|12949449||134823||222|MST||0|SPECIAL||SP|SPCA|External|0|10|||5|0||||||Robert|Foster|MAX REPAIR||||1|1|||300|Foster, Rob C|EA|0

Comment: последняя строка это на той, которой падает.

Comment: Известно расхождение между двумя данными способами, что `Files.lines` был оптимизирован в Java 9 для обработки строк (см. [implementation notes в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)), но насколько это могло повлиять на вашу проблему, тяжело сказать, не имея соответствующих тестовых данных.  Посмотрите на номера строк, в которых возникает проблема, проанализируйте их данные.  Возможно, следует изменить размер буфера при чтении данных (8192 байта по умолчанию), чтобы хватило для длинной строки.